# Light streaks leaking beyond frame of negative?

Tags: film, autofocus, minolta, light-leaks

I am using a minolta automatic camera - and for a few rolls of film now it has been producing streaks on the roll, usually in low light when there is one obvious light source. The camera is automatic so is probably using a longer shutter speed in low light - however I don't understand how the streaks are continuing outside the edge of the frame.  Is it a camera fault? Any ideas appreciated thanks! [image: streaks across right hand side]

[image: scan of strip of film - light sources seem to bleed across multiple frames]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how this would fit the mechanics of the camera, but that looks like it's winding the film on before the shutter is closed. No amount of poor user-handling would explain camera shake that could extend to the next frame.

Can you persuade it to believe there's film in & try it whilst you can see in the back, or hold it against your ear to listen for what's going on.

Comment: possibly the shutter is sticking and is jogged free when the film starts to advance? That would explain why the trails are longer at the bottom of the frame than the top...